PyQt5 QCamera no cameras available
I'm building a PyQt application where one widget is displaying a webcam video feed.
For the widget I basically use a lightly altered code from the QCamera example from geeksforgeeks.com.
The (minimal version of the) code I'm using:
class Camera(QCameraViewfinder):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Camera, self).__init__(parent)
        self.available_cameras = QCameraInfo.availableCameras()
        
    def select_camera(self, i):
        self.camera = QCamera(self.available_cameras[i])  
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self)
        self.camera.start() 

This works fine one my machine A (Arch on a notebook) but no available Cameras are detected one my machine B (freshly installed Debian on a Lenovo Thinkcentre). self.available_cameras is empty.
I use the same webcam (and have tried two different ones), they show up in dmesg as a USB HD Camera and I can access the camera feed via VLC, guvcview, etc...
I would appreciate any help and pointers to what the problem is.
It would be also insightful where PyQt gets its list of cameras from. thx!

UPDATE:
I was able to fix the problem, ekhumoro pointed me in the right direction. There were some qt packages missing, I (re)installed all of them by running:
apt install qtmultimedia5-*
The result was a error of a missing gstreamer library, so I installed gstreamer:
apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-*
Now the camera is discovered and the feed is displayed, however it lags a lot. But this is now a different problem.

Presumably, arch and debian provide different versions of Qt5. Are you using the official packages? Please update your question and show the specific versions of Qt5 you are using for testing.

@ekhumoro I updated the question, maybe you can be more specific which packages are of interest to you. thank you already in advance!

A pip-installed PyQt5 uses embedded Qt libs which are stuck at version 5.15.2. So the difference must lie elsewhere. On Linux, the QCamera classes rely on multimedia plugins that use gstreamer as a backend. It's therefore highly likely that your issue actually lies with gstreamer (or one of its many plugins). Hopefully, this will simply be a matter of ensuring all the necessary plugins are installed. You can check that gstreamer is correctly detecting your video devices by running gst-device-monitor Video/Source.
